# Silverlight application not funcitoning

Tags: silverlight, internet-explorer, silverlight-4.0, drag-and-drop

I have made a silverlight application for drag and drop uploading. Now, this application works fine when I deploy it from local server. But whenever I deploy it from QA server (machine on the same LAN but has a global ip associated with it), it does nothing. It just shows a white background screen (default parameter). There is no error that it couldn't find xap file or such, neither any other console errors as well.
I can't seem to figure out what the error is for.

As suggested by some other blogs and posts, I have tried to change the extension from xap to DLL, but still same thing.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

To access a silverlight app on a remote server, you need to put on the root folder of this server a ClientAccessPolicy.xml file.

A basic one, allowing you to use it from any domain:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<access-policy>
  <cross-domain-access>
    <policy>
      <allow-from>
        <Domain uri="*"/>
      </allow-from>
      <grant-to>
        <resource include-subpaths="true" path="/"/>
      </grant-to>
    </policy>    
  </cross-domain-access> 
</access-policy>
```

More details here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/cc197955%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Comment: But, according to the link, we need this policy only when we are accessing cross-domain functionality. In my case the access and everything is in the same domain only.
The problem in my case is that it's working when I deploy in on Tomcat from my m/c or any of my colleague's... but when I deploy it on QA server, it doesn't work. 
Maybe, I didn't get your point, but why should I use a cross-domain-policy for my case, when all I access is self-domain only.

Comment: Depending on your QA webserver con figuration, silverlight could think that you are in a crossdomain configuration, try with the suggested solution. I still not succeed, you must grab more details, try to get some informations using the chrome developer console (or the firefox one, but i prefer the one offered by chrome). You can also dig using Fiddler (freeware). If possible, look at the access & erros logfiles of your QA webserver too.

Comment: I tried with it.. but no gain. There isn't any error on console or on QA log also. In my code, on page load, I call a js function that return url for an image, and it gets loaded via silverlight and is displayed (this is the starting part only). But, on debugging js, the silverlight never calls the js function (but in local one, it gets called), so I am wondering if silverlight is being initialized properly or not. On righ clicking on the area however, it shows silverlight is present there. Confused.